# Proof by Fitch System

Tags: logic

I need to make a proof for the premise

((p ⇒ q) ⇒ p) ⇒ p

Using *only* Fitch System. The problem is that I have been trying for at least a week, but I just can't figure it out a way to solve the problem. I tried by assuming (p ⇒ q) ⇒ p and then proving that ~p implies a contradiction, but it's a dead end for me.

I would really apreciate any suggestion.

PD: Sorry for the bad english, It's not my native lenguage.

PD2: I can't use Natural Deduction. I can only use this rules: http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/glossary/fitch_system.html

Sorry for the double post, but a tag of "already answered" confused me. The other question is similar, but it makes use of natural deduction, while I can't use natural deduction.

Comment: Your Fitch system is quite similar to the natural deduction, so you can get a Fitch-style proof of the Pierce's law if you change $\bot$s to negation.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you're right.

Comment: You will have to use double negation elimination because pierce's law is well known to not be constructively valid.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have no premises, but only a goal, let's focus on the goal and think about how you can get to something like that. Well, the main connective is a conditional ($\rightarrow$), so the strategy is probably to use $\rightarrow \: Intro$:

[image]

OK, so now your (new) goal is to get to $P$, using $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P$

Well, there is still very little you can do with $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P$ by itself: $\rightarrow Elim$ requires you to have the antecedent $P \rightarrow Q$, which you don't have. So, let's once again focus on the goal ($P$), and think about how we can prove something like that.

Now, here is a trick to remember: in order to prove an atomic statement like $P$, one strategy is to try and do a proof by contradiction. Here is how that works in Fitch:

[image]

OK, so now the (newest) goal is to prove $\bot$ using $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P$ and $\neg P$.  OK, I won't show in detail how to do that, because at this point I want you to just look at the *proof skeleton* or *proof plan* that we have right now: do yourself a favor, and *make sure to come up with such a proof plan for whatever proof you are working on!* ... if your proof plan is good, the details will often pretty much fall out naturally.

For this particular proof, the rest isn't trivial, but it isn't hard either. Just think: "how do I get a $\bot$ given what I have? Well, that requires some statement and its negation. Hmm, I already have a negation $\neg P$. OK, so if I can get to $P$, I would be there.  How can I get $P$? Oh, I have a conditional $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P$ whose consequent is $P$, so if only I could prove the antecedent $P \rightarrow Q$ I would be there.  OK, how can I do that, presumably using $\neg P$?"

Well, I'll leave you to that. Good luck, and remember to rely on these proof skeletons!!

Answer (score 2):

When you have the law of the excluded middle at your disposal (or in your case, [double negation](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/glossary/negation_elimination.html) + [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Negation_Elimination_implies_Law_of_Excluded_Middle)), the easy way to prove all of these propositional logic questions is:

- for each variable $v_1 \dots v_n$, infer (or prove) $v_k \lor \lnot v_k$
- for each of the $2^n$ combinations of variables being negated or not, prove the theorem
- combine all cases using or elimination

So for your problem that looks like

$$\begin{array} {rll}
(1) & P \lor \lnot P & \text{Proven using the above links} \\
(2) & Q \lor \lnot Q & \text{Proven using the above links} \\
\\
(3) & \quad \quad P & \text{Assumption} \\
    & \quad \quad \vdots \\
(4) & \quad \quad ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P & \text{Fill in the dots} \\
\\
(5) & \quad \quad \lnot P & \text{Assumption} \\
(6) & \quad \quad \quad \quad Q & \text{Assumption} \\
    & \quad \quad \quad \quad \vdots \\
(7) & \quad \quad \quad \quad ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P & \text{Fill in the dots} \\
\\
(8) & \quad \quad \quad \quad \lnot Q & \text{Assumption} \\
    & \quad \quad \quad \quad \vdots \\
(9) & \quad \quad \quad \quad ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P & \text{Fill in the dots} \\
\\
(10) & \quad \quad ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P & \text{Or Elimination of 2, 6 - 7, 8 - 9} \\
(11) & ((P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P) \Rightarrow P & \text{Or Elimination of 1, 3 - 4, 5 - 10} \\
\end{array}$$

Establishing 9 can be a bit tricky, but the key is to notice that $\lnot P$, $\lnot Q$, and $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P$ is inconsistent so you can establish anything from it, including $P$.

Establishing 7 is straightforward, since if $Q$ is true, then $(P \Rightarrow Q)$ is true, then $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow P$ establishes $P$.